# Dynamically Create the new column name using the date_col variable and value_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, boxplot

It is possible to simplify the code, especially the lines where the cyl_ # columns are created.
This is an example code. But the real need is to create 12 columns. And make the boxplot graphs for each column.
It is a priority to use the data.table package

my code:

```
library(vioplot)
library(data.table)
dt=setDT(copy(mtcars))[,.(mpg,cyl)][]
dt[,mpg,keyby=cyl]

dt[cyl == 4,cyl_4:=mpg]
dt[cyl == 6,cyl_6:=mpg]
dt[cyl == 8,cyl_8:=mpg]
dt[,.SD,.SDcols=patterns("cyl_")]
> dt[,vioplot(.SD,col="gold"),.SDcols=patterns("cyl_")]
    upper  lower median    q1    q3
1: 33.900 21.400   26.0 22.80 30.40
2: 21.400 17.800   19.7 18.65 21.00
3: 19.025 11.625   15.2 14.40 16.25
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` for dynamical columns creation (which is possibly not necessary):

```
cyls <- sort(unique(dt$cyl))
dt[,(paste0("cyl_",cyls)):=lapply(cyls,function(x) fifelse(x == cyl,mpg,NA))]
dt[,vioplot(.SD,col="gold"),.SDcols=patterns("cyl_")]
```

[image]

Or with `ggplot2`, without columns creation:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt) + geom_violin(aes(x=paste0('cyl_',cyl),y=mpg),fill='gold') + 
             xlab('cylinders')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the OP is asking to create individual columns for each value of `cyl` (with many `NA` values in each column) but if the goal is to create a violin plot for each individual value of `cyl` this is what I would do:

```
library(vioplot)
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, vioplot(mpg ~ cyl, col="gold")]
```

> ```
>     upper  lower median    q1    q3
>     <num>  <num>  <num> <num> <num>
> 1: 33.900 21.400   26.0 22.80 30.40
> 2: 21.400 17.800   19.7 18.65 21.00
> 3: 19.025 11.625   15.2 14.40 16.25
> ```

[image]

This approach uses the `formula` parameter of `vioplot()`. There is no need for filtering or manipulating the `mtcars` data (except for coercing to class `data.table`).

---

If it is required to rename the labels on the x-axis this can be achieved by

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[, vioplot(mpg ~ paste0("cyl_", cyl), xlab = NULL, col = "gold")]
```

[image]

---

The `formula` parameter is quite handy as it allows for switching easily between different variables, e.g.,

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[, vioplot(hp ~ gear, col = "lightblue")]
```

> ```
>    upper lower median     q1    q3
>    <num> <num>  <num>  <num> <num>
> 1:   245    97    180 150.00   210
> 2:   123    52     94  65.75   110
> 3:   335    91    175 113.00   264
> ```

[image]

Comment: This is of course much easier! Didn't notice the `formula` parameter. Upvoted, and removed my `split` solution

Comment: Thank you, @Waldi! You are very kind.